# Rails ApplicationMailer method not called when invoked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to email from Ruby on Rails v4.2 using their `ApplicationMailer` mechanism. Unfortunately, at least in the development environment console, the subclass of `ApplicationMailer` we created doesn't call the method we tried to invoke:

```
class RecurringScheduleNotifier < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'
  def send_schedule_reminder(student)
    logger.debug('This never gets called :(')
    send_schedule_reminder_email(student, student.email).deliver
  end
  def send_schedule_reminder_email(user, email)
    mail(to: email, subject: 'Test subject')
  end
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.send_emails
    Student.all.each do |student|
      logger.debug('This does get called')
      RecurringScheduleNotifier.send_schedule_reminder(student)
      logger.debug('This also get called')
    end
  end
end
```

If I run the mailer directly in the console it sends the email just fine:

```
RecurringScheduleNotifier.send_schedule_reminder(Student.first)
```

All 3 logger messages are output as expected and the email is sent. However, if I call the `Student` class method from the console, this doesn't work:

```
Student.send_emails
```

I get no error messages, but only the 2 logger messages in the `Student` class are output. The logger message in `RecurringScheduleNotifier` is not output at all!

What am I missing? This is odd, since all `Student.send_emails` really does is call `RecurringScheduleNotifier.send_schedule_reminder` for each student (there is only 1 in my dev environment right now). And calling `RecurringScheduleNotifier.send_schedule_reminder` directly on that student works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a mailer method, the method returns an  `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery`. you have to call `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` to send the email.

So in your case, inside your user model, calling...

```
RecurringScheduleNotifier.send_schedule_reminder(student).deliver_later
```

...should do the trick.

I'm not sure about having two methods in your mailer though. You probably want to merge them into one. like:

```
def send_schedule_reminder(student)
  @student = student
  logger.debug('This never gets called :(')
  mail(to: student.email, subject: 'Test subject')
end
```

Comment: the `deliver` functions are clearly not the issue here though... as the first `logger` call never gets called.

Comment: @Sander seems to be correct. I just encountered same problem. User defined methods of action mailer’s subclass are not called without trailing `.deliver_now` or `.deliver_later` call. Note that when you define your mailers’s methods, you define _instance_ methods, but in your code you are calling _class_ methods, so here some Rails magic is involved, kind of lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Johann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815131/johann)'s comment, the `ActionMailer::Base` class has this peculiar way to call all theirs instance methods as class methods [here is the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.2/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L565-L571). What I don't know is why this and as long as I have seen only this class implements this "pattern" (¿?).